# Splitting numbers maybe using regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have an HTML textarea where the user inserts numeric serial numbers. These are either inline, separated by any character (including space), or in column coming from an excel file.

The serial codes can be 14 characters long if the first character is "1" otherwise they are always a length of 15 characters.

What I would like to achieve is a jquery function that reads the content of this textarea and generates upon submitting the form, an html table with each serial code in a new tr line of a table.

So far i tried to split codes submitted in column:

Input example:

```
12345678912345
12345678912346
12345678912345
223456789123455
623456789123457

$("#add_code").click(function(){
    var code = $("#code").val();

    for (line in code.split('\n')){
        $("#codes_list").append('<tr><td>'+code[line]+'</td></tr>');
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Please post your code and at least some examples for the possible input.

Comment: No one is going to write your code for you. Be specific about what you need help with.

Comment: Okay, but I charge $30/hour.  Do you have Paypal?

Comment: Sorry guys you are right. I just really need the regex

Comment: Can you reduce the delimiters to commas, semicolons, spaces, etc.? Having the delimiter be "any possible character" is going to be challenging.

Comment: Yes. I could try to reduce to spaces, commas, - etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you just want to split on any non-numeric?

```
code.split(/[^0-9]+/ig)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to write this for you but what I can tell you is you can use the pattern "[0-9]+" to match a continuous sequence of numbers.

A javascript regex result should allow for multi matches.

See examples here http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 0):

```
function parseSerialCodes(input) {
    var serialCodeRegExp = /(1\d{13}|\d{15})/g;

    var matches = [];
    var match = null;
    while((match = serialCodeRegExp.exec(input))) {
        matches.push(match[1]);
    }
}

$("#add_code").on("click", function () {
    var input = $("#code").val();
    var serialCodes = parseSerialCodes(input);

    var tableRows = serialCodes.map(function (code) {
        return "<tr><td>" + code + "</td></tr>";
    });
    var tableContents = tableRows.join("");

    $("#codes_list").append(tableContents);
});
```